# Extract symbology labels to attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, symbology, attribute-table

In Arcmap 10.5, I have a feature layer with soil types where there has been made labels under symbology. These labels do not appear in the attribute table of the feature layer although they are based on one of the columns, the column "class", in the attribute table. E.g. a "class" value of "1" has been made into the symbology label "Sand".

How do I transfer these symbology labels to a column of its own in the attribute table?

I could of course make a statement in field calculator, but considering the number of levels of "class", that would be very time consuming.

I have tried to search for if the question was already posted, but the only thing I have been able to find was [Export symbology to attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315862/export-symbology-to-attribute-table) and there the question is not answered.

Comment: If there is no domain table associated with this layer, try solution from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226885/arcgis-10-3-create-extract-summarize-data-from-unique-values-symbology

Comment: Thank you @FelixIP. However, I could not get that solution to work so I ended up creating a table with the "class" column and corresponding symbology label. Then I imported that table into Arcmap and used Join and relates/Join/join attributes from a table.